# Allow only draw rectangles - Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I found this great [script](http://geojason.info/demos/line-length-polygon-area-google-maps-v3/) with it you can "Line Length and Polygon Area", but i need it to let users draw only rectangles (90º angle).

I already change it to let users add just 4 points, but is not enough.

The original script lets you change the markers position. I would need that also, but if a user change the position of markers to be larger or smaller, it should keep the rectangle shape.

I'm working with jQuery / javascript.

Any one can help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only let the users add 2 points, use those as opposite corners of the rectangle (or use an [editable google.maps.Rectange](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#RectangleOptions), set its editable property to true, {editable:true})